# error: 'INT32_MAX' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I'm getting the error

```
error: 'INT32_MAX' was not declared in this scope
```

But I have already included

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

I am compiling this on (g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44) with the command

```
g++ -m64 -O3 blah.cpp
```

Do I need to do anything else to get this to compile? or is there another C++ way to get the constant "`INT32_MAX`"?

Thanks and let me know if anything is unclear!

Comment: @WalterTross baaaad baad idea,

Comment: @IanNorton, maybe you are right, but I still have to see a place where INT32_MAX is a different value

Comment: My Eclipse (Helios)/MinGW setup did not highlight <limits> as an error, and I was able to right click and open declaration, but I had to change 'include<limits>' to 'include <limits.h>' in order to stop INT_MAX reporting a 'not declared in this scope' error.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
 #include <cstdint> //or <stdint.h>
 #include <limits>

 std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::max();
```

Note that `<cstdint>` is a C++11 header and `<stdint.h>` is a C header, included for compatibility with C standard library.

Following code works, since C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>

struct X 
{ 
    static constexpr std::int32_t i = std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::max(); 
};

int main()
{
    switch(std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::max()) { 
       case std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::max():
           std::cout << "this code works thanks to constexpr\n";
           break;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a33984ede3f2f7e

Comment: Note that this isn't equivalent as it can't be used as a compile-time constant (pre-C++0x that is).

Comment: yes! This is what I am looking for, a C++ way to do it. Thanks

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: it can be used as compile-time constant. `const int MY_INT32_MAX = std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max();` will work just fine. This method is so simple that it will be optimized out as it would be explicitly defined constant.

Comment: If you use `<cstdint>` and compile with `-std=c++0x`, `INT32_MAX` is defined as a constant anyway (At least over here it is [GCC 4.4.4]).

Comment: Doc, its not a *compile-time* constant - you can't use that where the language requires an *integral constant*. Try `switch(1) { case std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max(): }` or `struct X { static const int i = std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max(); };`. I'm btw not saying `<limits>` is bad, just pointing out a difference.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche you were right, but this should be revised, cause C++0x does have `constexpr` and your examples should work now.

Comment: Pedantic: need to qualify `std::int32_t`, since the `.h` wasn't included and for the sake of good practice in general.

Answer (score 50):

Quoted from the man page, "C++ implementations should define these macros only when `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` is defined before `<stdint.h>` is included".

So try:

```
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#include <stdint.h>
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed that when reading the man page -_-, I need to wait 7 min before accepting your answer though...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also make sure you put that before any other include files that might include stdint.h without setting that define first.

Comment: 5 years later... still not the accepted answer :p Thanks, Blindy. That is a big help.

Comment: To be fair the accepted answer is just as good, arguably a more C++ way of doing things. This one is good to know too however.

Comment: Funny thing is that I provided my answer after yours as a supplement. Only since C++11 adds `constexpr` to `numeric_limits::max()` it became a real alternative.

Comment: Which man page?  The quotation seems to be missing a word or two (before _what_ is included?).

Comment: As a note, if you are still having problems with this when using a standard before C++ 11, try also including `<limits.h>` (instead of `<limits>`).

Comment: This was a gcc bug:  https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15366

Comment: @Blindy There was literally a word missing due to poor markup ;)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Fixed - was just an editorial issue with the answer. Does still need a citation though.

Answer (score 8):

Hm... All I needed to do was `#include <climits>` nothing else on this page worked for me.

Granted, I was trying to use `INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h> or <climits>
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue while using LLVM 3.7.1 c++ compiler. 
Got the following error while trying to compile gRPC code as part of building some custom library

```
src/core/lib/iomgr/exec_ctx.h:178:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'INT64_MAX'
```

The compilation went through after adding `-D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` as one of the options to c++ compiler.

```
.../bin/c++ -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I{LIBRARY_PATHS} testlib.cc -o testlib
```

Answer (score 0):

Including the following code after `#include <iostream>` worked for me:

```
#include <limits.h>
```

I am using the following compiler:

g++ 5.4.0-6

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the similar problem,just need to add-
`#include <limits.h>` after `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 0):

The code for all c++ version, compatible with lower GCC like CentOS 6.0(gcc version 4.4.7):

```cpp
// https://onlinegdb.com/ApNzDNYUx

#include <stdio.h>

// @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162072/17679565
#include <inttypes.h>

// For CentOS 6(gcc version 4.4.7) or not defined the macro.
#ifndef INT32_MAX
#define INT32_MAX (2147483647)
#endif

int main()
{
    printf("INT32_MAX=%d\n", INT32_MAX);

    return 0;
}
```

[OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/ApNzDNYUx)

Answer (score -1):

include             -->    `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`                 <--

should look like
:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
```

add this at the beginning.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/1458097)