# difference between stdint.h and inttypes.h

Tags: c, uint64, stdint

What is the difference between stdint.h and inttypes.h?

If none of them is used, uint64_t is not recognized but with either of them it is a defined type.

Comment: inttypes.h `#include`s stdint.h.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[See the wikipedia article for inttypes.h.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inttypes.h)

Use stdint.h for a minimal set of definitions; use inttypes.h if you also need portable support for these in printf, scanf, et al.

Comment: I came to stackoverflow to learn the difference between stdint.h and inttypes.h _after_ reading the wiki article which tells me that (u)intN_t is available in both. So what is the difference? Which should I include?

Comment: <inttypes.h> *includes* <stdint.h> and adds some printf macros. See Mikko Östlund's answer below.

Comment: I get: `fatal error: inttypes.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: @m4l490n Are you using `-std=c99`?

Answer (score 182):

### stdint.h

Including this file is the "minimum requirement" if you want to work with the specified-width integer types of C99 (i.e. `int32_t`, `uint16_t` etc.).
If you include this file, you **will get the definitions of these types**, so that you will be able to use these types in declarations of variables and functions and do operations with these datatypes.

### inttypes.h

If you include this file, you **will get everything that stdint.h provides** (because inttypes.h includes stdint.h), but you **will also get facilities for doing `printf` and `scanf`** (and `fprintf`, `fscanf`, and so on.) with these types in a portable way. For example, you will get the `PRIu64` macro so that you can `printf` a `uint64_t` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Only requires stdint.h to compile:
    uint64_t myvar = UINT64_C(0) - UINT64_C(1);

    // Requires inttypes.h to compile:
    printf("myvar=%" PRIu64 "\n", myvar);  
}
```

One reason you would want to use `printf` with inttypes.h is, for example, that `uint64_t` is `long unsigned` in Linux but `long long unsigned` in Windows. Thus, if you were to only include stdint.h (not inttypes.h), then, to write the above code and keep it cross-compatible between Linux and Windows, you would have to do the following (notice the ugly #ifdef):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Only requires stdint.h to compile:
    uint64_t myvar = UINT64_C(0) - UINT64_C(1);

    // Not recommended.
    // Requires different cases for different operating systems,
    //  because 'PRIu64' macro is unavailable (only available 
    //  if inttypes.h is #include:d).
    #ifdef __linux__
        printf("myvar=%lu\n", myvar);
    #elif _WIN32
        printf("myvar=%llu\n", myvar);
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a great answer (even though I didn't ask the original question!).  To add to Mikko's answer, inttypes.h copies in stdint.h (via preprocessor `#include`).  At least on my Linux system (GCC 4.5.2 and similar).