# Unable to open include file 'inttypes.h' in Borland C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm using Borland C++ Builder, I wrote a class where I had to use this header "inttype.h" because I'm using 'int64_t'. the problem is I have this error telling me it can open this include file:

```
[C++ Error] RSA.h(3): E2209 Unable to open include file 'inttypes.h'
```

in Code::Blocks I didn't have this problem, so I thought C++ Builder doesn't have this file, so I added 'inttypes.h' from Code::Blocks directory to my project in C++ Builder but still the same error.

how can I surpass this problem ? or if I can't include this file, what are long integer variables I can use instead of 'int64_t' ?

EDITED:

my `C++ Builder` version is `6`

thanks, I finally found a solution is one could say. instead of using `"inttypes.h"` I used `"stdint.h"`
but still wondering, can this `stdint.h` do all the things `inttypes.h` can do ?

Comment: `inttype` or `inttypes` ?

Comment: inttypes , but I tried inttype after reading your comment, same result. @mangusta

Comment: :-) i mean, probably the header file is called `inttype.h` while you use `#include "inttypes.h"`

Comment: What version of c++ builder?

Comment: please also take look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597025/difference-between-stdint-h-and-inttypes-h  and the wikipedia article linked there

Comment: C99 header files are not very popular with C++ tool vendors, they break too much existing code.  That language is in dire need of namespace support to ever evolve.  Just provide your own substitute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inttypes is a c99 header. probably your compiler does not fully support c99.
you may try `#include <cinttypes>` which is the c++ variant. or the more basic stdint.h or cstdint

Comment: @vlad_teesch same problem with '#include <cinttypes>'  
but I solved the problem using '#include<stdint.h>'

Comment: 2016 update: Embarcadero C++Builder Seattle 10 still does not have cinttypes. A truly terrible product. :(

Comment: C++Builder 10.1 Berlin still doesn't have it (but most times stdint.h is enough).