# C++ INT32_MAX was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

```
INT32_MAX was not declared in this scope
```

What is the solution for this (error occurred in C++) ?

Comment: Did you include `<cstdint>` or `<stdint.h>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: 'INT32\_MAX' was not declared in this scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233054/error-int32-max-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <cstdint.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
 char ch;
 cout <<INT32_MAX << end;
 cin >> ch;
 return 0;   
}                                                                      this is the program i had written but this isn't working

Answer (score 2):

`INT32_MAX` is defined in `<stdint.h>`. You need:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

in the offending source file.

Comment: Yes I included it                                             #include <iostream>
#include <cstdint.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
 char ch;
 cout <<INT32_MAX << end;
 cin >> ch;
 return 0;   
}

Comment: The header should be either <stdint.h> or <cstdint>, not a combination of both, as in your case (<cstdint.h>).