# C++ file including C header file

Tags: c++, c, g++, header-files

I need to include a C header file in my C++ project but g++ throws "not declared in this scope" errors.
I read that i need to use extern "C" keyword to fix it but it didn't seem to work for me.

Here is a dummy example triggering this error.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C"
{
#include "includedFile.h"
}
int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 1212;
    std::cout<< "Hello World!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

includedFile.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
enum TypeOfEnum {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE,
    FOUR = INT32_MAX,
};
```

The error thrown is :

```
$> g++ main.cpp 
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
includedFile.h:7:9: error: ‘INT32_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
FOUR = INT32_MAX,
```

I saw on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233054/error-int32-max-was-not-declared-in-this-scope) that I may need `#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` without any success.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: why is there a comma after `INT32_MAX`?

Comment: yes, but why did you put it there? You don't put a comma after the last thing in an enum, do you?

Comment: @genisage The comma-after-last-item is actually allowed for enum declarations.

Comment: A comma at the end of a enum declaration is legal.

Comment: The code works for me, using g++ 4.8.2.

Comment: @RSahu Doesn't compile with g++ 4.8.1 on Coliru unless you specify C++11; does compile with Clang 3.4 though.

Answer (score 0):

`<cstdint>` is a C++11 feature. Pass `-std=c++11` to your compiler.

Comment: Forcing to C++11 doesn't seems right in my case, for portability issues.

Comment: @fdeslaur ...then don't use a C++11 feature.