# find the minimum value entered while using infinite loop c++

Tags: c++, loops, borland-c++

My task is to find the minimum number between n input values that the user should enter in an infinite loop until a certain number or character is entered to stop the loop.

The problem that I am facing is, I can't get the condition that tests the input to see which of the entered numbers is the smallest to work. Also, a second problem is, I want to end the loop with a char not an int, but I don't know if that is even possible.

I searched online but I can't find any answers.

Side note: I am new to C++. I am using Borland C++ v5.02.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int I, min =0;
cout<<"Enter a number :";

do{
    cin >> I;
    if (I < min){
        if (I > 0){
            min = I;
        }
    }
}while (I > -1);

cout << min;
```

Comment: you can't have `continue;` with `min=I;` after it because `continue;` restarts the loop immediately and `min=I;` never gets executred.  You don't need the `continue;` at all.

Comment: Also make sure you initialize `min` to a really large number (like `INT_MAX` if it is an `int`)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I did a little bit of searching and I tried to initialize min to INT_MAX but it gives me an error about  #include <bits/stdc++.h> that it Unable to open include file 'bits\stdc++.h'

Comment: don't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` - it isn't a real header: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h   `INT_MAX` is a standard C++ thing so you should `#include <climits>` for C++ and `#include <limits.h>` for C: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits

Comment: Nitpick: Maybe don't use a compiler that hasn't updated in 21 years...

Comment: @JerryJeremiah thanks the `<limits.h>` worked for me and the program is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with the code was with the header I couldn't find a one that was working with my compiler Borland v5.02 c++ but thanks to @JerryJeremiah he leads me to it.

also, I redeclared the `min =INT_MAX;` because I am using this code in a loop.

the code is working with me now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()
{
     int I, min =INT_MAX;

     cout<<"Enter number of input :";

            do{
              cin>>I;
                if (I<min ){

                    if(I>0){
                         min =I;
                    }
                }

                }while(I>-1);

           cout<<min;
         min =INT_MAX;
         getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved your problem by using a [try-catch block](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_exceptions.asp) and [stoi()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/).

`stoi()` is used to convert a string into a number. If the number input is not convertible (meaning that a `char` is entered and the loop should break), `const std::invalid_argument & e` is catch and automatically break the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Min = INT_MAX; string I; int x;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a number or a char : ";

        cin >> I; 
        try
        {
            x = stoi(I);
            if (x < Min)
            {
                if (x > 0) {Min = x;}
            }
        }
        catch(const std::invalid_argument & e) {break;}
    }
    while(x > 0);

    cout << "Minimum positive number entered : " << Min;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a number or a char : 10
Enter a number or a char : 8
Enter a number or a char : 5
Enter a number or a char : 7
Enter a number or a char : a
Minimum positive number entered : 5
```

As your code is a bit unclear, I changed both constraint to `I>0`, and you can easily modified this bit.

For the prolem with `INT_MAX`, maybe `#include <climits>` or `#include <limits.h>` will help, as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233054/error-int32-max-was-not-declared-in-this-scope). If the problem persist, the workaround is to set `Min` to something high, for example `10^9`.

*Note: Ran on Code::Blocks 20.03, Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: still have the same problem Error:  project.CPP(3,22):Unable to open include file 'climits.h'

Comment: @ToqaOs If the problem persist, maybe just try setting `Min` to something high, probably 1e9?

Comment: @ToqaOs do not include `<climits.h>` include `<climits>`